# If post author ID is..show that

Tags: author

i would like to display a custom adrotate Group everytime if a user ID matches the script.
So i created:

```
if (is_author('1'))
{
echo adrotate_group(8);
}
elseif (is_author('70'))
{
echo adrotate_group(8);
}
 elseif (is_author(''))
{
echo adrotate_group(8);
}
```

This aint working, i see no output in my single php. Can somebody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `is_author()` is used to check if you are on the archive page for the specified author. So as your code is in `single.php` this will never be true.

From the docs

> This Conditional Tag checks if an Author archive page is being
>   displayed. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE
>   or FALSE.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_author

To get the author ID you could use:

```
$author_id = get_post_field('post_author', get_the_ID());
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) this is explaining why i can't see any Output =)

Comment: Inside the loop you can just use `$post->post_author`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but will this work in my case to if i need the Author ID? Currently this is working `<?php

$author = get_post_field('post_author', get_the_ID());

if ($author == '1') {
   echo adrotate_group(8);
} elseif ($author == '35') {
   echo adrotate_group(9);
} else {
  echo adrotate_group(8);
}
?> `